# When are the partition numbers squares?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integer-partitions

I'm unsure if this question is even interesting. I am playing around with partition numbers $p(n) :=$ # partitions of $n$, and I noticed that $p(n)$ never really is a square number, except for of course $n = 0, 1$. Is there a simple reason for this?

It also seems to be similar for other modified partition numbers, such as $p_{t}(n) :=$ #t-regular partitions of $n$ (none of its parts are divisible by $t$), at least for $t = 2, 3, 4$ and a few more. In these cases the only square $p_{t}(n)$ are when $p_{t}(n) \in \{0,1\}$. For example, $p_{11}(n)$ is square (apparently) only when $0 \leq n \leq 6$, in which case $p_{11}(n) \in \{0, 1\}$.

It gets a little weirder when we consider $p_{s, t}(n) :=$ #s-regular **and** t-distinct partitions of $n$ (no part appears $t$ or more times). For example, when $(s, t) = (7, 9)$ we have $p_{7, 9}(0) = 1 = p_{7, 9}(1)$ and $p_{7, 9}(11) = 49$, $p_{7, 9}(44) = 35721 = 189^2$. (It is also somewhat interesting that the input/outputs are either divisible by 7 or 9). These are the only ones up to $10^4$ (very slow program so hard to go past this). For convenience, the generating function for $p_{7, 9}(n)$ is $\prod_{n\geq 1} \frac{(1-q^{7n})(1-q^{9n})}{(1-q^{n})(1-q^{63n})}$. Somewhat similar results for other pairs of $(s, t)$.

Maybe this has to do with the generating functions?

Comment: What was you search limit ? I currently run the range upto $n=10^6$

Comment: $p(10^5)$ has already $347$ decimal digits and upto this limit, there is no further perfect square.

Comment: I did $10^4$ on $p(n)$ and $5000$ on the others. I can up it I just haven't done that! Anything new with $10^6$?

Comment: @Peter That's what I would expect. Interesting...

Comment: Not yet finished, but I also search for perfect powers $p(n)$ , $n>1$. $p(n)$ is no perfect power for $2\le n\le 10^5$

Comment: Not sure whether PARI/GP can also compute easily the generalized partition-numbers.

Comment: For the perfect powers , I extended the search range to $3\cdot 10^5$ , still no example. The $10^6$ routine for the perfect squares has not yet finsished, but there is still no further example (not really surprising :) )

Comment: @Peter Well it's not so bad just computing their generating functions, e.g. $\sum p_{t}(n)q^{n} = \eta(t^{2}z)/\eta(z)$.

Comment: Oops, I meant $\eta(tz)/\eta(z)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141574/discussion-between-peter-and-freddie).

Comment: @ThePhoenix I was on my way to using a more probabilistic approach to get somewhere - thanks for doing that! Seems like squares get pretty far apart as $n$ grows, and since $p(n)$ (for example) grows very quickly, it ought to skip over almost all (if not all) of the large squares. Anyway, I still think this is interesting for those who like partitions ;-) Although I agree that $p(n)$ probably isn't special within the general context of the question.

Comment: Also, it may be helpful to note that there isn't really a modular forms approach off the top of my head to penetrate this problem. There are approaches in the theory that allow one to argue about the indices $n$ for $p(n)$ (e.g. if they're in square classes or arithmetic progressions or...), but not easy ones for this!